# Trouble installing Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am having difficulty installing Pygame on Python 3.8 (MacOS)

When I attempt to run `install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`, I get the following error message:

```
Installing collected packages: pygame
 Running setup.py install for pygame ... error
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 
  ....

        36 warnings and 8 errors generated.
        error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:.
```

When I attempt to import Pygame into my project I get ***ModuleNotFoundError*** (as expected).

Thank you in advance for any advice on how to resolve this issue!

Comment: Did you try the the commands in the official web page? https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip installed (I think macos comes with it) you can run:
`pip install pygame`
If you still can't import try
`pip3 install pygame`

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot believe it was such an easy fix.